# Unable to install JRE8/JRE7 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

I downloaded JRE8 from the Oracle site (`jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg`). Then I opened `dmg` and run the installation. The installation progress started, but then the following error occurred:

```
The installation failed.

The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

The same error if I try to install JRE7.

I also tried to download `jre-7u71-macosx-x64.tar.gz` and unpack it, but after that Java refused to work correctly. `java -version` is fine, but the following code prints `Unknown`:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
```

This is very strange. Has anyone run into the same issue?

**UPDATE 1**

I run `sudo diskutil repairPermissions /`

Then I run the installer again and pressed `⌘ + L`. The log is:

```
installd[438]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
installd[438]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Java 8 Update 25.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f8442b3a440 {NSFilePath=./postinstall, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/Java%208%20Update%2025/Java%208%20Update%2025.pkg#javaappletplugin.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.oracle.jre, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Java 8 Update 25.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postinstall";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cJava 8 Update 25.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/Java%208%20Update%2025/Java%208%20Update%2025.pkg#javaappletplugin.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.oracle.jre";
    }
Installer[1667]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Installer[1667]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Installer[1667]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Comment: Try repairing your disk permissions with DiskUtility, then run the installer again. If you still have the issue don't close the installer, but press `Command-L` `( ⌘ L )` and post the log results.

Comment: @l'L'l I did everything what you said

Comment: @l'L'l Did you mean pkg, not dmg? I run `md5 /Users/<user_name>/Desktop/Java\ 8\ Update\ 25.pkg` and got a different sum, not `2a93...` (I got `90f4...`)

Comment: Yes, the `.dmg` is `2a93...` and `.pkg` is `90f4...` - Try running the `.pkg` from your desktop or use the Terminal instructions in my answer and see if you have success. If neither of those work the only other immediate suggestion I have is rebuilding launchservices from terminal: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

Comment: @l'L'l Performed everything you said in your answer. Got the same error. Then run `/System/Library/Frameworks/...`, but it didn't help.

Comment: @l'L'l I just installed Apple's Java 6 and then run JRE8 installer. Now the installation of JRE8 finished successfully, but I do not see any JRE8 files in the filesystem. `java -version` says 1.6.0_65.

Comment: Hmmm, you might want to run the OS X installer again, and reinstall the OS — it won't erase your data, and should fix whatever else may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It appears either you need to update the Apple version of Java, or that the installer is getting mucked after downloading it somehow. The problem can usually be fixed by running the update tool and re-downloading the JRE package from Terminal:

Open Terminal and run these commands:

```
softwareupdate -ir
```

Check/Update Apple's version of Java if it's needed.

```
cd ~/desktop
curl -v -j -k -L -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg > jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Downloads the JRE disk image to your desktop.

```
mkdir ~/desktop/jre
hdiutil attach -mountpoint ~/desktop/jre jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Mounts the disk image.

```
sudo installer -pkg ~/desktop/jre/Java\ 8\ Update\ 25.pkg -target /
```

Installs the JRE package.

```
hdiutil detach ~/desktop/jre
```

Unmounts the disk.

```
java -version
```

Checks Java version.

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Comment: @I'L'I, the sudo installer command gives me the following: `installer: Error - You are trying to install Java 8 Update 25, however Java 8 Update 77 build 03 is already installed` but `java -version` command says `-bash: java: command not found`.

Comment: I get an error `installer: The upgrade failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)` when I execute `sudo installer -pkg ~/desktop/jre/Java\ 8\ Update\ 25.pkg -target /`